# Rails 5 httparty Model debugging cant test if its working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi there i have the following item.rb That i made in a rails model.

/app/models/item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool'

  def initialize(name, description, price, icon_url)
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.price = price
    self.icon_url = icon_url
  end


  def self.find(name)
    response = get("/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=#{name}")
    if response.success?
      self.new(
      response["item"]["name"],
      response["item"]["description"],
      response["item"]["current"]["price"],
      response["item"]["icon_large"]
      )
    else
      # this just raises the net/http response that was raised
      raise response.response
    end
  end
end

item_test = Item.find("227")
puts item_test
```

As you can see its a very simple model im new to rails 5 / fairly new to rails all together and i don't know how to test if its functioning. The puts does not seem to output anywhere. I have also tried logger ect. But to no avail. Does anyone know the best way to tell if this is functioning / debugging.

So please how do i test if this is functioning ?

Sorry if this question is to simple. Im just really stuck and cant seem to find a answer thank you in advance ill be sure to respond quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your test from `rails console`

```
$ rails c
> item_test = Item.find("227")
```